# Embedding gnuplot 5 window into Gtkmm 3

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I am trying to embed the gnuplot window into my application using the socket/plug concept in gtkmm 3 library. I have followed the example in the official page [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-plugs-sockets-example.html.en) and everything works as expected.

Then I moved to embedding gnuplot window. I modified the socket.cpp as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gtkmm/socket.h>

using namespace std;

class MySocketWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
  public:
    MySocketWindow()
    {
        auto socket = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Socket());
        add(*socket);

        cout << "Socket id is: " << hex << socket->get_id() << endl;

        show_all();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example.socket");
  MySocketWindow win;
  app->run(win);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile/build the code with:

```
g++ --std=c++11 socket.cpp -o socket `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

And run it. A black socket window appears with `Socket id is 3e0000b` message printed on the terminal.

```
.\socket
```

Then I run gnuplot in x11 terminal with the corresponding window id above:

[image]

Now when I `plot sin(x)` in gnuplot, I am expecting the socket window to show the plot, but nothing happens. What I am doing wrong here?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit.

Comment: Possibly related: [Cannot embed gnuplot x11 window into Gtk3 socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209199/cannot-embed-gnuplot-x11-window-into-gtk3-socket?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem on gnuplot's site - see my [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209199/cannot-embed-gnuplot-x11-window-into-gtk3-socket?rq=1) question. Now it's left to find how to fix it on the socket's site.